# UIButton retains the glows after it has been touched

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uibutton

Hi i am making customUIButtons in my app by using the following piece of code.

```
+ (NSArray *) createButtonItemNormalImage:(UIImage *)normalImage
                       highlightImage:(UIImage *)highlightImage
                        disabledImage:(UIImage *)disabledImage
                      touchUpSelector:(SEL)selector
                               target:(id)target
{

 // HighlightImage is not used. Highlight is shown using iOS glow
UIButton *uiButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
uiButton.bounds = CGRectMake(0,
                             0,
                             normalImage.size.width,
                             normalImage.size.height);
[uiButton setImage:normalImage
          forState:UIControlStateNormal];

if (disabledImage)
{
    [uiButton setImage:disabledImage
              forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
}
[uiButton addTarget:target
             action:selector
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

uiButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;

UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:uiButton];

return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:buttonItem, uiButton, nil];
}
```

I have made a cancel button using the above function. The cancel button takes the user from one screen to another screen. The problem is when i come back to the first screen the cancel button is still glowing. I have seen this problem before also but a call to `[self.view setNeedsLayout]` used to solve it.

Why does it happen and what would be a correct way of solving it? 
Thanks!

Comment: uiButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES; TO uiButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = NO;

Comment: @DarshanKunjadiya I want the button to glow only when it is touched. Setting uiButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = NO will make the button not glow at all. The problem is it glows even when it is not being touched.

Comment: I'm having this same problem with just one of six buttons on a view. All six are configured identically, but for some reason only one of them fails to "unglow" after being touched. Very frustrating. I've regenerated the offending button several times but nothing seems to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem in not so standard way I now set the highlighted state to no for all the buttons when I enter the first screen. I use `myButton.highlighted = NO;`. However the documentation says following for `highlighted` property.

> Specify YES if the control is highlighted; otherwise NO. By default, a control is not highlighted. UIControl automatically sets and clears this state automatically when a touch enters and exits during tracking and when there is a touch up.

Its not happening so in my case.I would love to know the reason behind it and standard ways of solving it